# Checking for matching tags

Tags: java, html, string, tags, character

So I have a question that I can't seem to find the answer to so say I have a line of text that contains not only letters but also angle brackets like

```
"<X>Hello, Welcome!</X>"
```

Now how could I read that line of text and check for any characters like  and then check to see if it can find closing set to match it and if it didn't display an Error message but if it did it would display Correct message.

Any help or hints on this would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: I remember something called: XML factory, you can use it to detect the things you need

Comment: That looks like XML, so you should probably use an XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

```js
re = /<(\w+)>.*<\/(\w+)>/i;

function check(str) {
  match = str.match(re);
  if (match && match[1] == match[2]) return true;
  return false;
}

str1 = "<X>Hello, Welcome!</X>";
console.log(str1,check(str1));

str2 = "<X>Hello, Welcome!</x>";
console.log(str2,check(str2));

str3 = "<X>Hello, Welcome!</Y>";
console.log(str3,check(str3));
```

I know that an actual parser would probably be better for this, but I figured that regular expressions were still worth a shot.